# get matching bracket on ace js editor

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Is there a way to get the position of the matching bracket on ace js editor?

So let's say that I am iterating through the lines and tokens like this

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
var session = editor.getSession();
for(var i = 0; i < session.getLength(); i++){
   var tokens = session.getTokens(i);
   for(var j=0;j<thisTokens.length; j++){
       if(tokens[j].value == '{'){
           // how to get position of the closing bracket here?
       }
   }
}
```

I notice that ace has this
https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/edit_session/bracket_match.js

but I am just not so sure on how to utilize it. It's not in the API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

From the Ace Documentation library, you can use jumpToMatching() function in order to get the position of the Matching Bracket position

```
editor.jumpToMatching();
var matchPosition = editor.selection.getCursor();
```

matchPosition should give you matched bracket Position.

Answer (score 1):

there is `editor.session.findMatchingBracket` function https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.6/lib/ace/editor.js#L522